# IEEE 802.11 packet capture using java

Tags: java, network-programming, wireless

Is there any java libraries which can be used to capture IEEE 802.11 frames [Wireless link layer frames]?

Comment: jpcap: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the java network interface doesn't directly expose the lower layers of the protocol so this is not possible in java at this time without resorting to native library gymnastics.

[jpcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) does some of this for you, using PCAP native libraries.

There's another project of the same name that does similar - [jpcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpcap/) and may be of use

Comment: thanks. But I was looking for monitoring wireless connections specifically. seems like they are not supporting. :(